# With Entity Framework Core, how can a make a table relation cross two joins?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following POCO classes I've setup in Entity Framework Core 7, I want to be able to assign a Contact Type to a Client then when assigning a Contact to a Matter I should only be able to pick a Contact Type that is assigned to the Client that the Matter is assigned to.

I can probably work around this in code but I'd like my database integrity to follow this as well if possible.

As you can see from the select statements I was easily able to insert a Contact with the wrong Contact Type.  Matter 7 is a child of Client 9, and has a child Contact 7, which has a ContactType of 7, but that ContactType should only exist for Matters of Client 10.

I've not done anything in the context in OnModelCreating and I think this is probably what I'm missing but I don't understand it very well.

Do I need to join Matter to ContactType on the Matters.ClientId = ContactTypes.ClientId?  How would I do that?

```cs
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ClientFlag Flags { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Matter> Matters { get; set; } = new List<Matter>();
}

public class ContactType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public Client Client { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class Matter
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public Client Client { get; set; }

    public string MatterCode { get; set; }
    public string MatterName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ManagingFeeEarnerId")]
    public User ManagingFeeEarner { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } = new List<Contact>();
    public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset InsertDate { get; set; }
    public string OtherParty { get; set; }
    public StatusType StatusType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CustomProperty> AdditionalProperties { get; set; } = new List<CustomProperty>();
}


public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MatterId")]
    public Matter Matter { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContactTypeId")]
    public ContactType ContactType { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public ushort Order { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Database Diagram]

[image: Database Content]

Comment: Looks like table Contacts is a many-to-many but the keys are wrong. MatterId and ContactTypeId should be the PK and FK.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I could only have 1 Contact per matter?  Matter 1 - * Contact and ContactType 1 - * Contact I think are correct.  Although I'm struggeling to work out in SSMS if they were created as One to Many or not.